# C - The variable 'p_prvy' is being used without being initialized

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, pointers, linked-list

I am trying to compile my code but I am not able to compile it. I am using VS 2010 and I get this message:

> 'Tel_zoznam.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
>   Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'p_prvy' is being used without being initialized.

It stops at `p_prvy->next = NULL;`

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#define MAX 31

typedef struct ZOZNAM{
    char meno[MAX];
    char priezvisko[MAX];
    char cislo1[MAX];
    char cislo2[MAX];
    char cislo3[MAX];
    struct ZOZNAM *next;
} ZOZNAM;

int main(void){
    char c;
    ZOZNAM * p_prvy;
ZOZNAM * p_akt;
    p_prvy->next = NULL;
    int z;
    p_akt=p_prvy;

    printf(" Pre pridanie kontaktu do zoznamu stlacte 'p'\n Pre vypis zoznamu zadajte 'v'\n Pre ukoncenie programu zadajte 'k'\n");
    z=pocet_zaznamov();
    printf("%d",z);
    while(1==1){
        scanf("%c",&c);

        switch(c){
            case 'p': vlozit(p_akt); break;
            case 'v': vypis(p_prvy); break;
            case 'n': nacitanie(p_akt); break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `main()` function, you have the following declaration of the `p_prvy` variable:

```
ZOZNAM * p_prvy;
```

Almost immediately after that, you say:

```
p_prvy->next = NULL;
```

Which means you are using `p_prvy` variable. However, it is not being initialized and so has unspecified value. This is called [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), or simply UB.

What you need to do is initialize that pointer. For example, by allocating some memory:

```
ZOZNAM * p_prvy = (ZOZNAM *)malloc(sizeof(ZOZNAM));
```

You may also have it initialized to NULL, but then dereferencing NULL will take your process down.

Comment: Please, don't do that cast, my eyes vomit allocated memory from that!  You should also use `sizeof(*p_prvy)` instead of `sizeof(ZOZNAM)`.

Comment: @H2CO3: I am 100% with you on that, however, there is also a #C++ tag on this question, and so I have decided to go with something that compiles in both cases.

Comment: again, one does not simply tag questions as `C/C++` because that's not a language :P :) And I see your rationale, however, `sizeof(ZOZNAM)` is still dangerous (in C++ too).

Comment: @H2CO3: Well, I don't see that as a big issue. I mean I see it, but I don't think `*p_prvy` makes it less of an issue. You can mess up and assign the result to a wrong variable, for example :-)

Comment: well, you won, but read the Kernel coding style guide anyways :)

Comment: @H2CO3: I do kernel coding, and read the style, too. By the way, you are talking about µC/OS or FreeBSD kernel? :-D

Comment: @H2CO3: I have based our company's coding style on that one. It is not bad I would say. So I am with you on pretty much every topic, are you giving me +1 or what?

Comment: I'm giving you an upvote because you spread the good practice.

Answer (score 5):

It tells you pretty much what the error is: you use a variable before initializing it, thus you're invoking undefined behavior.

```
ZOZNAM *p_prvy;
p_prvy->next = NULL;
```

is wrong, because you haven't allocated memory for `p_prvy` yet you dereference it. Make a constructor function for your data type (and think about your design).

Comment: is it c or c++ if c code is used is it possible to set a constructor ?

Comment: @MehdiKaramosly It doesn't matter, practically. One can write OO-style code in C, when a function that wraps `malloc()` and sets initial values for a data structure is also called a constructor.

Comment: I've found http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf a fairly comprehensive overview of OO-style C.

Comment: @Bracketworks: That's a very old, very good book. Highly recommended.

Comment: @VladLazarenko That's what I love about timeless principles; resources that convey them well become timeless themselves.